# postgres docker container does not start

Tags: postgresql, docker

I had a postgres docker container that was running before but does not start anymore. Is there a place where I can look for the errors. The postgres log does not show any error (just the previous successful shutdown). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured. docker logs can be viewed with "docker logs ". Per that I figured it's the wider permission.

FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has group or world access
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).